# MySQL Date-Format

Tags: php, mysql, date, datetime

I have a MySQL-Table with lots of dates in it. In my query I'm getting the date in the format YYYY-MM-DD.

```
$date = $sql->getValue("date");

echo $date;
// Output: 2016-12-19
```

Is it possible to get an output like `Monday, 19.12.2016`?

Comment: Yes it's possible in SQL only.  To accomplish this you'd use  [`DATE_FORMAT`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_dayname) `select DATE_FORMAT('2016-12-19','%W %d.%m.%Y')` returns: `Monday 19.12.2016` http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/03e686/8/0

Comment: Thank you! Is there a way to get the Weekday in German?

Comment: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/locale-support.html may explain it better than I can in a comment something like `SET lc_time_names='de_DE'` may do it.  though it depends on the German variant you want.